# Efficient conditional validation of large dataset in python

Tags: python, performance, validation

I have a simple/flat dataset that looks like...

```
columnA columnB columnC
value1a value1b value1c
value2a value2b value2c
...
valueNa valueNb valueNc
```

Although the structure is simple, it's tens of millions of rows deep and I have 50+ columns.

I need to validate that each value in a row conforms with certain format requirements.  Some checks are simple (e.g. `isDecimal`, `isEmpty`, `isAllowedValue` etc) but some involve references to other columns (e.g. does `columnC` = `columnA` / `columnB`) and some involve conditional validations (e.g. if `columnC` = `x`, does `columnB` contain `y`).

I started off thinking that the most efficient way to validate this data was by applying lambda functions to my dataframe...

```
df.apply(lambda x: validateCol(x), axis=1)
```

But it seems like this can't support the full range of conditional validations I need to perform (where specific cell validations need to refer to other cells in other columns).

Is the most efficient way to do this to simply loop through all rows one-by-one and check each cell one-by-one?  At the moment, I'm resorting to this but it's taking several minutes to get through the list...

```
df.columns = ['columnA','columnB','columnC']
myList = df.T.to_dict().values() #much faster to iterate over list
for row in myList:
    #validate(row['columnA'], row['columnB'], row['columnC'])
```

Thanks for any thoughts on the most efficient way to do this. At the moment, my solution works, but it feels ugly and slow!

Comment: Ultimately if every value on every row needs to be looked at, then looping through the rows and columns and looking at every value is the fastest thing you can do. Libraries like Pandas can improve running time compared to vanilla Python by being partially implemented in a language that executes faster than Python. Python itself is effectively single-threaded, so another option to boost speed would be multiprocessing,

Comment: My first stab at it would go like this: Divide the file size by the number of CPU cores, jump to the respective offsets in the file and seek to the next newline. Split the file into chunks at those locations and do the mundane checks (validity) on each chunk with parallel processes, one per CPU core. While doing so, let each process build the data structures you will need for cross-validation (such as dicts or sets). After the mundane checks are through, join those data structures into one and do the cross-validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating over rows is very inefficient. You should **work on columns directly using vectorized functions or Pandas functions**. Indeed, Pandas store data *column-major* in memory. Thus, row by row  accesses require data from many different locations to be fetched and aggregated from memory. *Vectorization* in not possible or hard to achieve efficiently (since most hardware themselves cannot vectorize this). Moreover, Python *loops* are generally very slow (if you use the mainstream CPython interpreter).

You can work on columns using Pandas or **Numpy** directly. Note that Numpy operation are much faster if you work on well-defined **native types** (float, small integers and bounded strings, as opposed to Python objects like unbounded strings and large integers). Note also that Pandas already store data using Numpy internally.

Here is an example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'columnA':[1, 4, 5, 7, 8], 'columnB':[4, 7, 3, 6, 9], 'columnC':[5, 8, 6, 1, 2]})

a = df['columnA'].to_numpy()
b = df['columnB'].to_numpy()
c = df['columnC'].to_numpy()

# You can use np.isclose for a row-by-row result stored into an array
print(np.allclose(a/b, c))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to *split* your dataset into smaller pieces and parallelize computation.
For validations part , type, or schema i suggest to use a library like [voluptuous](https://pypi.org/project/voluptuous/) or others, i found a schema very maintainable approach.
Anyway, as told by @jerome vectorial approach can save you a lot of computational time